# How to disable the views behind a view in Android?

Tags: android-layout, listview, view, android

I have a LinearLayout with a ListView like this:

```
Training.XML

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/head_buttons"></include>
        <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/programmes" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This LinearLayout is included in a FrameLayout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/training_page"></include>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="60"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:id="@+id/countdown" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_icon"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" android:textSize="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

The TextView "countdown" will be always shown up if I need it. And now i wish that I can disable all the items in the ListView so that the users can not click on them. What I tried in code is:

```
  //disable other views behind，
                for (int i = 0; i < programListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = programListView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

But it doesn't work correctly, I can still click on the items behind the text view. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a parameter in your custom ArrayAdapter, exp `boolean mIsListEnable = true;`

2) Override **isEnabled** function:

`@Override 
  public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
       return mIsListEnable;
  }`

3) create a setter for this parameter:

```
public void setEnabled(boolean value){
   mIsListEnable = value;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you defined your list item in a layout like so?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if(convertView == null) {
    // Inflate a new View every time a new row requires one.
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, parent, false);
}
   ...
}
```

You could try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < programListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = programListView.getChildAt(i);
                EnableDisable(true,child);
 }


private static void EnableDisable(boolean enable, ViewGroup layout) {
    //layout.setEnabled(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            EnableDisable(enable, (ViewGroup) child);
        } else {
            child.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kristy Welsh Thanks for the answer! I tried your solution but sorry it did the same thing like my codes. But my problem was solved just now with a "dialog".